# Laravel Paginate: Save record and return to the correct page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a paginated list of records, a user can edit a record; this fires my update method;

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $questionUpdate=$request->all();

    $question = Question::find($id);
    $question->update($questionUpdate);
    return redirect('questions');
}
```

But it loses the page (for pagination) it was on.

How do I make it redirect to the correct route/page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that doing the following resolved my requirements.

1. Put in the following in your form

   `{!! Form::hidden('redirects_to', URL::previous()) !!}`
2. In your update method on your controller, assuming successful save with no errors;

   `$url = $request->only('redirects_to');`

   `return redirect()->to($url['redirects_to']);`

This seems to work for my requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects):

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: This doesn't take URL parameters (like pagination) into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The following method might be more easier.

Pass the previous URL with its parameters to the view, using the URL facade, and the method *previous()*.

Here's an example: (In your controller)

```
public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('layouts.blog.post', ['post' => $post, 'previous_url' => URL::previous()]); // pass in the page
    }
```

Inside your view, make use of the variable you passed in, *previous_url* to make an anchor, or a form, etc..